# Google Nexus 4 suddely stop even battery is not empty

Tags: battery, nexus-4, reboot, operating-system

My Google Nexus 4 suddenly began to stop unexpectedly at random times. After few times I could not even boot up the OS. I could recover by factory reset wipe from the recovery mode. Unfortunately sudden stop issue persisted even after factory wipe. Then I flash factory image according to [this androidcentral post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-4-rooting-roms-hacks/223923-guide-nexus-4-factory-image-restore.html). Now OS is up and running, but sudden stopping is still there when disconnected from charging cable. Phone works fine when connected to main power line. Though phone stopped suddenly, battery is not empty, I can boot up again and live for few seconds still.

Is this a hardware failure or some battery cache?

Answer (score 0):

If the your phone crashes even after flashing a fresh rom, It's probably a hardware issue. Does your phone heat up?

Comment: No, it does not heat up abnormally. So last option is to replace the battery?

Comment: It could be your battery but it would be odd if a damaged battery issue got temporarily fixed just by a factory reset don't you t think?

Comment: original issue never got fixed, not even temporarily. Factory reset helped to boot up os which again stopped suddenly